# How can I implement Solr case insensitive and accent insensitive substring search with whitespaces?

Tags: search, solr

I store 120000 wine records in a SQL Server database. Until now I've searched successfully for wine names by performing the following SQL:

```
WHERE (LOWER(Wine.name) LIKE '%" + (searchString) + "%'")
```

I am now in the process of switching over to using Solr. I would like to search for "clos rene" and get "Clos Réné" back. However Solr is returning all records that match 'Clos' and all records that match 'Réné'. I've have tried the following field definition:

```
<fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Could someone please help me define the correct field type so that I can reproduce my SQL query above to return case insensitive and accent insensitive results for multiple words with white space in between?

I have also experimented with wildcard searches using filed type 'string', but I can't get it to work as case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
<fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**EDIT:** Ok now i get your question , added extra : `<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>`  try this.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't solve my problem. Now, if I query:
   wineName:*clos*
I get all "clos" wines regardless of case or accent, but I can't then search for:
    wineName:*clos rene* or wineName:*clos r*
I want to allow the user to search wines with double or multiple names. Is that possible?

Comment: Now i understand that you have wild card in the front, Look at my updated analyzer portion. Let me know.